# I get an error when i try to trian ssd model

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

i get this error when i try to train ssd model .

```
ValueError: Cannot assign value to variable ' WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor/WeightSharedConvolutionalClassHead/ClassPredictor/bias:0': Shape mismatch.The variable shape (12,), and the assigned value shape (30,) are incompatible.
WARNING:tensorflow:Detecting that an object or model or tf.train.Checkpoint is being deleted with unrestored values. See the following logs for the specific values in question. To silence these warnings, use `status.expect_partial()`. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restorefor details about the status object returned by the restore function.
W0608 12:25:20.801542 22648 checkpoint.py:204] Detecting that an object or model or tf.train.Checkpoint is being deleted with unrestored values. See the following logs for the specific values in question. To silence these warnings, use `status.expect_partial()`. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restorefor details about the status object returned by the restore function.
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).save_counter
W0608 12:25:20.803523 22648 checkpoint.py:213] Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).save_counter
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.iter
W0608 12:25:20.803523 22648 checkpoint.py:213] Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.iter
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.decay
W0608 12:25:20.804506 22648 checkpoint.py:213] Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.decay
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.momentum
W0608 12:25:20.804506 22648 checkpoint.py:213] Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.momentum
```

my tensorflow is fine because before this i train an object detection model .

i get another error when i run this code . Maybe the first error happens because of this error . But even though I receive an error, it seems that there is no problem and the file is created and it is not 0 kilobytes .

```
!python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join(paths['IMAGE_PATH'], 'train')} -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'train.record')} 
!python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join(paths['IMAGE_PATH'], 'test')} -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'test.record')}
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\od\Tensorflow\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\scripts\generate_tfrecord.py", line 168, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "E:\od\Tensorflow\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "E:\od\Tensorflow\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "E:\od\Tensorflow\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "E:\od\Tensorflow\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\scripts\generate_tfrecord.py", line 158, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "E:\od\Tensorflow\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\scripts\generate_tfrecord.py", line 112, in create_tf_example
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  File "E:\od\Tensorflow\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 114, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "E:\od\Tensorflow\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 76, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: Tensorflow\workspace\train\455.jpg : The system cannot find the file specified.

; No such file or directory
```

there is no 455.jpg at all.

test.record is fine but when I run the tfrecord generator it gives me the train.record error.

```
Successfully created the TFRecord file: Tensorflow\workspace\annotations\test.record
```

i change the test.record name to train.record because i want test that is first error happens when i get this error but i get that error again .